# How to count weekdays between two data.frame columns(fields) in R

Tags: r

eg. df got 2 columns named as c("Today", "Expiration"). I want to get a new field as "Workdays". But I failed when I wrote like this:

```
Today <- seq.Date(as.Date("2015-10-01"), as.Date("2015-10-11"), by = "days")
Expiration <- seq.Date(as.Date("2015-10-20"), as.Date("2015-10-30"), by = "day")

df <- data.frame(Today, Expiration)

df <- transform(df, Workdays = sum(!weekdays(seq.Date(Today, Expiration, "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")))
```

Error in seq.Date(Today, Expiration, "days") : 'from' must be of length 1

The warning is "Today" should be length of 1.

Please help me out, thank you!

Maybe calculate directly works better

```
d <- with(df, Expiration - Today)
d <- as.numeric(d)
Workdays <- d - ((d - 1) %/% 7 ) * 2 - ifelse(d %% 7 == 0, 2, ifelse(d %% 7 == 6, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example, Also in `transform`, we use `=`

Comment: Thank you^ ^. I am new to use R, wondering there may be many simple ways to complish this. In other programming languages, I would like to for/foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`, grouped by sequence of rows (`1:nrow(df)`), we get the `sum` of the logical condition and assign (`:=`) that as new column ('Workdays').

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Workdays:=sum(!weekdays(seq(Today, Expiration, by = 'day')) %in% 
                         c('Saturday', 'Sunday')) , 1:nrow(df)]
```

Comment: wow, nice code. I also tried the basic way, in which may be quicker. Thank you